# how to check if bazel installed in my machine?

Tags: bash, bazel

I have installed bazel on Ubuntu and I am writing a bash script that contains a function that checks if bazel is already installed or not.

I do not know how to invoke this.

Can someone help on that?

this is my code:

```
function InstallBazel{
  if[ bazel dos not exist]; then
     # Add Bazel distribution URI as a package source
     sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg -y
     curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor >bazel-archive-keyring.gpg
     sudo mv bazel-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings
     echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/bazel-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list

     # Install and update Bazel
     sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **dpkg** command with the **-l** option to list all installed apt packages, and filter the output with the specific key "bazel", using the grep command.
Then you have to check grep return value.
(grep returns 0 when the filter matches, 1 when it does not).

```
function InstallBazel{
         sudo dpkg -l | grep bazel 2>&1 /dev/null
         if[ "$?" != "0" ]; then
            # Add Bazel distribution URI as a package source
            sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg -y
            curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor >bazel-archive-keyring.gpg
            sudo mv bazel-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings
            echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/bazel-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
    
            # Install and update Bazel
            sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel
    }
```

Comment: `if ! dpkg --verify bazel 2> /dev/null; then : proceed with install; fi`